# Is there any way I can have snippets (like yasnippet) but for a particular file?

Tags: yasnippet

Sometimes files have quite specific snippets that might be useful? Is there any easy way to have per file snippets?

## Approach

I've got some code that get hold of the snippet text for a desired snippet. However I don't know how to expand this with yassnippet.

```
(setq my-snippet "class $1(parent):")
(my-yas-expand my-snippet) ;; how do i expand this?
```

This looked hopefully, but I was getting `(void-function nil)` when I tried to use  this.

```
(with-temp-buffer (insert s) (yas--parse-template))
```

At this point I gave up as requiring me to understand too much of yas's internals..

Comment: If you want a certain snippet to be expanded when you first create a certain file https://github.com/mineo/yatemplate is an option

Comment: Also, [this discussion](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/936) might be interesting to you (I only quickly skimmed it b.t.w.)